# Grammar of “Yo en viajado”?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, selección-de-palabras, expresiones, significado

I don’t understand what this means and how “en” and the past participle work together?

I’m guessing it’s something like “me traveling a lot”? The context was [this](https://youtu.be/KzdFSxURKvo) video around 1:43.

Does “en” also carry the meaning of like “as” or “in the state of” here?

And could I get some other examples with this same structure? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

He seems to be saying, "Yo, enviajado."  I have two ideas.

1. *Enviajado* might be equivalent to *sesgado*.  In architecture there is a type of slanted arch which can be called an *arco enviajado* or *arco sesgado*. 
   *Sesgado* is kind of like "skewed."  So, the speaker may have been talking in a self-deprecating way, saying that he might have had a lot of bad dreams due to being a bit screwed up, or off in the head.
2. On the other hand, the English caption in the video says "high," and this seems plausible.  Here's another [example](https://prezi.com/5nuvm4l_heya/sustancias-psicoativas/) I found:

   > Existen varias maneras de introducir esta sustancia: una de ellas es por vía oral, los efectos tardan en manifestarse entre 30 minutos y una hora y, según la dosis, pueden durar entre ocho y diez horas, cuando se coloca en el ojo la reacción se produce casi instantáneamente más o menos entre tres a nueve minutos, el efecto potente en el que se puede catalogar totalmente a la persona "ENVIAJADA" dura de una a dos horas

   Some documentation found by @guifa: 2008 scholarly article "[ASPECTOS MORFOLÓGICOS Y CAMBIOS DE FORMA EN LA CREACIÓN LÉXICA DE LA JERGA ESTUDIANTIL](http://www.redalyc.org/pdf/442/44248783007.pdf)" mentions that *enviajado* means *estar drogado.*

   So the translation would be:

   > Maybe that was just me, **tripping**.

   Note, *tripping* can be literal (e.g. on an LSD trip) or figurative (in a weird space).

About the grammar: it's a sentence fragment.  Here's another, following the same pattern:

- *Context: two people looking at family photos together* Tú, disfrazado de payaso.  *([This is] you, dressed up as a clown.)*

Comment: Number 2 is most probably it. *En-...-[a|i]do* is extremely productive.

Comment: @pablodf76 - I didn't understand your second sentence -- can you explain further?

Comment: Confirmado que significado drogado: https://revistas.ucr.ac.cr/index.php/kanina/article/download/4113/3939/ (es un PDF pero menciona que enviajar = estar drogado)

Comment: Morphology (e.g. prefixes and suffixes) is "productive" when speakers can and do make new words with it. Coining *en-X-ado* from a root X is very common, so it's productive.

Answer (score 0):

**Enviajarse** is, according to the [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=1PrcoTLRdx0ADrQEHbO),

> I.    1.  intr. prnl. *Ho.* Hacer planes para un viaje próximo.
> [*To make plans for a future journey*]

The speaker is asked about the meaning of his dreams and he just says that maybe they are premonitions, like he making a future journey.